# How to find a missing value from another table

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Imagine if I had two tables like this:

```
Table Name: user
| id | user_id | password |

Table Name: permissions
| id | admin | write | delete | transfer |
```

And populated the tables with this:

```
Inserting into user table:
    - 0, joshsh, asdf01
    - 1, jakesh, asdf02
    - 2, annsh, asdf03
    - 3, lamsh, asdf04

Inserting into permissions table:
    - 0, yes, yes, yes, yes
    - 1, yes, yes, yes, yes
    - 2, no, yes, yes, yes
```

And I didn't add in the 4th value into the `permissions` table. How would I query a statement as to find which numbers I forgot (in case it was a big database)?

Comment: if you want to find all the missing values of permission table then . left outer join permission table on the base table user on `ID` column.Null values in the user table will indicate the missing records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to get the same result, these are two possible ways:

With a NOT EXISTS:

```
SQL> select u.*
  2  from user_ u
  3  where not exists (
  4                      select 1
  5                      from permissions p
  6                      where u.id = p.id
  7                   );

        ID USER_ID    PASSWORD
---------- ---------- ----------
         3 lamsh      asdf04


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 3342498783

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |             |     4 |   160 |     7  (15)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN ANTI    |             |     4 |   160 |     7  (15)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| USER_       |     4 |   108 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| PERMISSIONS |     3 |    39 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - access("U"."ID"="P"."ID")

Note
-----
   - dynamic sampling used for this statement (level=2)
```

And with an outer join:

```
SQL> select u.*
  2  from user_ u
  3       left outer join permissions p
  4         on (u.id = p.id)
  5  where p.id is null;

        ID USER_ID    PASSWORD
---------- ---------- ----------
         3 lamsh      asdf04


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 3342498783

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |             |     4 |   160 |     7  (15)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN ANTI    |             |     4 |   160 |     7  (15)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| USER_       |     4 |   108 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| PERMISSIONS |     3 |    39 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - access("U"."ID"="P"."ID")

Note
-----
   - dynamic sampling used for this statement (level=2)
```

Notice that Oracle did the same explain plan for both statements, considering that the test has been made with two very small tables with no indexes and no statistics.
Also, consider that there are many ways to get the same result; performance strongly depends on you data, stats, indexes, ...

ps I used `USER_` instead of `USER`, to avoid problems.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the id column is the join between the permissions and user tables based on the id column (and that id is the primary/unique key in both tables), here are a couple of solutions:

```
select id from permissions
minus
select id from user;
```

or

```
select * from user
where id not in (select id from permissions);
```

Comment: Good point; what I was after was assuming that id was the join column. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

By applying count(*) on both the tables if they are not equal then alert will be generated and that altert can be generated using sql server agent job.
or you can do this
Select * from user as u
 full outer join permissions as p 
on a.id in(select id from user)

Comment: Did you try to run the run the query ?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use LEFT JOIN with and IS NULL in where clause, it's elegant and efficient in every aspects:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM user u 
LEFT JOIN permissions p ON u.id = p.id
WHERE p.id IS NULL
```

Comment: "it's elegant" - I disagree and think that `SELECT id FROM user MINUS SELECT id FROM permissions` is much more elegant. No big deal, just not something to shout about :)

Comment: My main concentration is on huge data operation so thanks for sharing this and I will try it :)